# How to write a login for java GUI

Tags: java, user-interface, authentication

so I know that there are many similar questions to mine but i do not really understand what they mean as i am not that great when it comes to coding.

my login screen in the GUI is this:

```
public void createLoginPanel()
{
    loginPanel.setLayout(null);

    loginLbl.setLocation(425,50);
    loginLbl.setSize(500,50);
    loginLbl.setText("Login");
    loginPanel.add(loginLbl);

    usernameLbl.setLocation(250,300);
    usernameLbl.setSize(250,50);
    usernameLbl.setText("Username: ");
    loginPanel.add(usernameLbl);

    usernameTxt.setLocation(350,300);
    usernameTxt.setSize(250,50);
    usernameTxt.setText("");
    usernameTxt.setColumns(10);
    loginPanel.add(usernameTxt);

    passwordLbl.setLocation(250,400);
    passwordLbl.setSize(250,50);
    passwordLbl.setText("Password: ");
    loginPanel.add(passwordLbl);

    passwordTxt.setLocation(350,400);
    passwordTxt.setSize(250,50);
    passwordTxt.setText("");
    passwordTxt.setColumns(10);
    loginPanel.add(passwordTxt);

    loginBtn.setLocation(675,400);
    loginBtn.setSize(100,50);
    loginBtn.addActionListener(this);
    loginBtn.setText("Login");
    loginPanel.add(loginBtn);



    gotoWelcomeScreenBtn2.setLocation(100,600);
    gotoWelcomeScreenBtn2.setSize(150,50);
    gotoWelcomeScreenBtn2.addActionListener(this);
    gotoWelcomeScreenBtn2.setText("Home");
    loginPanel.add(gotoWelcomeScreenBtn2);

    }
```

the login i currently have is this:

```
   if(e.getSource() == loginBtn)
    {

        String pass;
        String user;
        user = usernameTxt.getText();
        pass = passwordTxt.getText();



        if(user.equals("username") && pass.equals("pass") )
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Login successful");
            allTheGUITabs.setSelectedIndex(7);
        }   
        else
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please try again.");
        }     

        System.out.println("Login Button pressed");
    }
```

i want to login using existing info that i have stored in a text file called "employeelist.txt" and i am not sure how to do this.

edit: i have changed the login to user.equals and pass.equals but i am still unsure on how to login with anything other than what i've declared.

edit:

this is the contents of my text file. the second is the username and the third is the password. how will i scan this text file to ensure that the username and password match?

1,MSmith01,Pass123,Mark Smith,12 Yellow Lane,L34GF4,07837463

2,JSmith02,Pass456,Joan Smith,8 Green Road,L394RQ,08765456765

3,PSmith03,Pass678,Paul Smith,9 Orange Street,L435RE,07485747362

4,WSmith04,Pass910,Walter Smith,8 Green Road,L394RQ,08765456765

5,CSmith05,Pass149,Callum Smith,12 Yellow Lane,L34GF4,07485848373

6,MSmith06,Pass213,Mark Smith,32 Red Road,L384GT,07874636472

7,TMath07,Pass141,Terry Matthews,4 Peach Street,L219RB,07564737283

Comment: You're comparing the component instead of the string. Your IDE should warn you about that.

Comment: I don't use an IDE this is for my coursework in college and we were told that we can't use an IDE

Answer (score -1):

Let’s say you have next strings in your txt file

```
admin
qwerty12345
```

Use scanner and pass values for your variables reading them from txt

```
File employeelist;
Scanner scanner;
 String login;
 String password;
 try
 {
   employeelist = new File("employeelist.txt"); // changed code 
   scanner = new Scanner(employeelist); //changed code 
   while(scanner.hasNextLine())
   {
     login = scanner.nextLine();
     password = scanner.nextLine();
   }
 }catch(FileNotFoundException e)
 {
   e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

Then use it in your if statement.

```
if(user.equals(login) && pass.equals(password)
{
 // your code here
}
```

Comment: would i need File employeelist = new File("employeelist.txt"); if i already have EmployeeList elist = new EmployeeList(); ? also, it is saying that Scanner cannot be found as well as FileNotFoundException.

Comment: and does it matter if my text file looks like: admin,qwerty1234 with like 8 other rows of data including like id,username,password,name,number

Comment: @JessH yes cause I wrongly pointed on new File and Scanner outside try catch block, and this is first , secondly I hadn’t got any idea how your txt file looks like and what data had been written in it. I just supposed , and my answer based on my assumptions. If you want to get wide answer with all stuff related to your issue , you should describe what you want exactly with all details, and should not change main point after you get your answer